# How to convert output value from input field from string to number dynamically

Tags: typescript, input

As form input elements always return the `string` values if you entered the numbers. How to convert those strings into number dynamically.

i.e, If user entered `"123212"` in input field, I want to get the output data as number `123212`.

If user entered `"asdfas"` in input field, the output data should be string only `"asdfas"`.

Comment: `Number(field.value)`

Comment: But that is not possible if input data looks like this "asafasd", right?

Comment: I'm not sure what "impossible" means here. Have you tried to run the `Number` function with that string?

Comment: yes I have tried, if I tipp "asdfasd", then I got value: NaN

Comment: Sure, so? .....

Comment: The input value is dynamic, you can tipp number and string, but I want to have output data also the same type.

Comment: You can check if it's `Number.NaN` (using `Number.isNaN()`), if it is - the value is not convertible to a number, hence it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
field.value = (parseInt(field.value)) ? parseInt(field.value) : field.value
```

Comment: `parseInt` is too permissive, `Number()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
// get the button and make it respond to a click
var theButton = document.getElementById("output");
theButton.onclick = getTypeOfOutput;

// this function runs each time the button is clicked
// the simple function is called within this one 
function getTypeOfOutput() {
 // get the text from input field
 var inputText = document.getElementById("input-text").value;
  // check for the text entered is string or number.
  var onlyNumbers = (inputText.match(/^\d+$/)) ? 'number' : 'string';
  // write the result into the HTML
  document.getElementById("output-type").innerHTML = onlyNumbers;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter text : <input type="text" id="input-text" size="4"></p>

<button id="output">Get Output</button>

<p>Type of output : <span id="output-type"></span></p>
```